# Do councillors influence each other?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I had my spymaster studying technology in Constantinople; when I sent my chancellor there as well to fabricate claims, the Study Technology (50 tech points) event seemed to fire much faster, as if it were using the combined Intrigue of both councillors (3 times in one year). Does this actually happen, or was it just a coincidence?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is a coincidence. But someone would have to peek at the game files to be 100%.